# How do I fix Visual studio 2010 error message "CCHandler uninitialized" when running WP7 XNA projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna

When I try and run a Windows Phone 7 project it fails and displays a message box:

```
"CCHandler uninitialized"
```

In the errors window is a single error:

```
"No target is available for deploying."
```

And it won't run. I've tried a full uninstall+reinstall of both visual studio and all the WP7 tools and the problem remains.

It's the same for totally new projects and for several existing projects I have that run fine on my other PC.

Also, the options for where to deploy (Emulator/Device) seem to be missing from the project properties and toolbar.

WP7 silverlight projects also fail, but with a different popup (and no message in the errors window):

```
"Exception from HRESULT: 0x89721800"
```

I've tried just running the WP7 emulator from the start menu and nothing happens (no error, nothing)

Does anyone have any ideas?

<sub>Visual Studio 2010 pro. (I've tried with and without SP1)

Windows 7 pro x64.</sub>

Comment: Weird. Did the installation complete with no errors? What version of the Windows Phone tools are you using?

Comment: @liortal: Yes. Completed fine both times, no errors. Downloaded the latest version of the WP 7.0 tools from [app hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started), with the Jan 2011 update and the Fix. Not the 7.1 Beta 2 stuff.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using ? Also, can you confirm you have these files, as shown here: http://www.pasteall.org/23081/text

Comment: @liortal: Visual Studio 2010. (Initially with SP1, but after it failed I uninstalled everything and the second time I tried without SP1). I'm using version 7.0 of the tools, so for a start they are in the 7.0/ directory, and I'm also missing some. CapDetect, IsolatedStorageExplorerTool, WPConnect are missing from the tools directory.

Comment: Have you contacted the Windows Phone Developer Tools team? looks like something got screwed with the install.

Comment: @liortal: No, and I've had to send the laptop back for replacement now (unrelated issue, dead pixels on screen) so I can't dig any further. I'm hoping it all just works fine on the replacement, if not I'll get in touch with them directly then. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great, update if there's anything interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging this appears to be caused by installation order of SP1.

If you install VS2010 SP1 before the phone 7 tools, it does not appear to correctly install, and even an uninstall and reinstall of VS does not appear to fix the problem. (although perhaps I wasn't finding everything that needed to be uninstalled)

I would recommend that you follow this install sequence:

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. Phone tools (all of them, from the app hub site, in the order they recommend)
3. VS2010 SP1

[This applies to the initial releases of the phone 7 tools, I don't know what the situation is with the mango beta tools]